# Route53 Multivalue answer persisting single record

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, linux-networking, amazon-route53

We use Route53 for our private DNS, specifically the Multivalue Answer Routing Policy, with no Health Checks for dump/lazy load balancing.

This has worked well for us, up until yesterday where we're noticing odd behaviour.

We have a record set for `ro.mysql.foo.bar.com`, which contains the IPs of our read-only MySQL replicas.

If you run a DIG it reflects this;

```
dig A ro.mysql.foo.bar.com

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ro.mysql.foo.bar.com. IN   A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ro.mysql.foo.bar.com. 4 IN A    10.2.2.2
ro.mysql.foo.bar.com. 4 IN A    10.2.2.3
ro.mysql.foo.bar.com. 4 IN A    10.2.2.4
```

The expected behaviour is when mysql hits `ro.mysql.foo.bar.com` it connects to one of the 3 hosts at random, in a dumb/random load balanced kind of way. This worked fine up until yesterday.

If I run

```
mysql -h ro.mysql.foo.bar.com -e "select @@hostname;"
```

I'd expect the output of `@@hostname` to vary between `10.2.2.2`, `10.2.2.3`, and `10.2.2.4`

Instead, it doesn't route traffic randomly across the three IPs, it will take one and only use one.

```
+-----------------------------------+
| @@hostname                        |
+-----------------------------------+
| 10.2.2.3                          |
+-----------------------------------+
```

If we remove `10.2.2.3` from the DNS will it stop using it. If we add it back in, it'll then continue to use only `10.2.2.3` again.

We do run our own resolver via PowerDNS (which we're phasing out), but doesn't appear to be any fault there that we can see, PowerDNS has had it's DNS cache purged too.

Comment: If you `dig @ns-xxxx.awsdns-yy.zzz your-record.example.com` where `ns-xxxx.awsdns-yy.zzz` is one of the name servers assigned to your hosted zone by Route 53, does the returned record ordering vary?  Or, if this is a private hosted zone, the NS records are possibly dummy values, so try `dig @169.254.169.253 your-record.example.com` from inside the VPC.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, the ordering varies. We've tested this on the AWS nameservers and our own, both show the same behaviour.

Comment: So dig varies.  Does `ping your-record.example.com` repeatedly try to ping only one host, or does that also vary, but only the `mysql` client doesn't?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ping shows the same behaviour too, returns the single IP and does not vary

Comment: Initial impression, this sounds like it could be the work of my old nemesis, [`nscd`](https://serverfault.com/q/729738/153161).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I read similar things too, but we don't have `nscd` installed on our servers

Comment: And this has been working all along, but suddenly changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74491/discussion-between-adamstrawson-and-michael-sqlbot).